# How does the compiler know which class the lambda is implementing?

Tags: java, lambda

I see [`Thread()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#constructor.summary) takes both `Runnable` and `String` for single argument constructors. How does the compiler know that a `lambda` is implementing a `Runnable` class and not a `String` class?

```
    (new Thread( () -> {
        System.out.println("Deleting stats...");
    })).start();
```

Maybe it goes by the number of methods in the class/interface? But what if a class had multiple constructors that took single argument class that only had one method, for example:

```
Thread( Runnable r );
Thread( Comparable c );
Thread( ActionListener al );
```

What happens then when you try to implement a `lambda` then? How would the compiler know which class the `lambda` is implementing?

Comment: You have `Runnable` and `String` and only one of that is a suitable functional interface, so the it is quite easy to choose the correct constructor. This will help you, might even be a dupe: [What is use of Functional Interface in Java 8?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36881826). Also helpful: [Functional interfaces in Java 8](//stackoverflow.com/q/22794665)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java compiler must choose a functional interface type for the type of a lambda expression.  This is governed by the [JLS, Section 15.27.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3), which states:

> A lambda expression is compatible in an assignment context, invocation context, or casting context with a target type T if T is a functional interface type (§9.8) and the expression is *congruent* with the function type of the *ground target type* derived from T.

The type `String` is not a functional interface type, but `Runnable` is.  The lambda takes no arguments and returns no data, so it is *congruent* with `Runnable`.

More generally, the types of parameters in a lambda expression must match the types of parameters of the single abstract method of a functional interface type, and the return types must match also.

In your example, each of the 3 functional interface types is distinct, so at most one will match.  If there are multiple functional interface types that could possible match, that would be ambiguous, only resolvable by casting the lambda expression to the intended functional interface type.

Comment: Can you give an example of casting a lambda? I've never heard or seen that before.

Comment: e.g. `(Runnable) ( () -> { System.out.println("Casted lambda as Runnable!"); } )`

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expressions are converted to an instance of a class implementing a functional interface. A "functional interface" means an interface with only 1 (non-default) method in it.

String isn't an interface - it's a class. So the compiler looks at the lambda expression and knows that if the code is to make sense then it should convert the lambda to instance of an implementation of Runnable, as it's the only possible thing that could work!

Comment: What if there are multiple constructors that take a functional interface?

Comment: Then the compiler will try to disambiguate based on the "shape" of the functional interface, e.g. taking into account the numbers and types of the arguments, which might well be different for the different possible constructors that take a functional interface.